# SQL: Ignore irrelevant JOIN when aggregating over the core table

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

Suppose I have Tables:

```
dbo.Purchases
Id | Value | UserId
1 | 10.00 | 3
2 | 1.00 | 1
3 | 15.50 | 2
4 | 13.40 | 1

dbo.Users
Id (UQ) | Name
1 | Bob
2 | Sarah
3 | Alex
```

And a VIEW:

```
dbo.PurchasesWithUsers

SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Purchases
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Users ON Users.Id = UserId
```

And I'm going to run `SELECT SUM(Value) FROM dbo.PurchasesWithUsers`.

Now ... as a human, I can see that that JOIN doesn't affect that query:

- It's obviously not directly used in the `SUM`.
- It's a `LEFT JOIN` so it can't *exclude* `Purchase` rows.
- It's joining to a column with a `UQ` constraint so it can't *duplicate* `Purchase` rows.

But when I run the query and look at the execution plan, the Engine (MS SQL Server) is still performing the JOIN, which degrades the performance :(.

**Is there any way that I can give the engine additional clues that it can work out that it could completely skip the JOIN, whilst still using the VIEW as the thing I'm querying?**

---

*Context:*

- *Obviously the tables are huge which is why the performance impact is material*
- *The Tables and the View are obviously a little more complex than that, but not actually all that much - the logical simplification is still valid, and the UQ constraints are explicit (as either UQ CONSTRAINTs or UQ indexes).*
- *The VIEW is being used so that the users can filter on a variety of different options. The Data API process those options and applies the relevant `WHERE` clauses to a single `VIEW`. Alas that means various of the JOINs aren't relevant to the VIEW depending on what filters have been chosen :(*
- *I'm aware that I could materialise and directly index the VIEW, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible, given that I can see that a simpler query plan could logically exist already.*

Comment: The solution is the not use your `VIEW` to do this. Use `SELECT SUM([Value]) FROM dbo.Purchases;`. The other table (`Users`) does need to be considered, as if there were a one to many relationship, the total sum of `[value]` would be different. So the rows need to be checked.

Comment: _"..the logical simplification is still valid..."_ We would like to believe that but it generally is not a correct assumption. Post the plan, the query, and DDL for the objects involved. Absent the necessary detail, only guessing is possible. The optimizer can be quite clever and "see through" useless joins. It is also rare for a query to sum everything in a table (no matter the grouping) - especially huge tables. Seems there is much more to this than posted.

Comment: @Larnu. No, it doesn't. Because it *can't* be a one to many, since it has Uniqueness constraints defined, as already described.

Comment: *"No, it doesn't."* You know that, @Brondahl . SQL Server will still need to check that. And the easiest way is the therefore perform the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Unless indexed, a view does not exist as a stored set of data values in a database. The rows and columns of data come from tables referenced in the query defining the view and are produced dynamically when the view is referenced. Because you don't want to "**directly index the VIEW**", there is no other data to work with and the server is getting the data by using the query behind the view so there is no work around to avoid that `LEFT JOIN` with this approch.

Comment: The majority of this is talking about the nature of VIEWs. I'm fully aware of that - the interesting question is whether you can get a query with a JOIN to ignore that JOIN if it doesn't impact the result.